# Feathers services usage and eslint

Tags: node.js, eslint, feathersjs

In order to add some user data to my rides list, I added this hook:

```js
async (context: HookContext) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
  for (const ride of context.result.data) {
    if (typeof ride.driverId !== 'undefined') {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      const driver = await context.app.service('users').get(ride.driverId);
      // We can't copy the complete object because field are not filtered by the internal service.
      // @see https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1715
      ride.driver = {
        _id: driver._id,
        name: driver.name,
      };
    }
  }
},
```

ESLint, configured with Airbnb recommendations, throw errors `no-restricted-syntax` and `no-await-in-loop`.

I understand why, but I don't know how to make it working without.

What is the correct and working syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The restricted syntax rule doesn’t want you to use `for-of`.

I’d consider something like a map iterator and see if that doesn’t resolve both issues e g

```
return context.result.data.map(ride => {
    if (typeof ride.driverId !== 'undefined') {

      const driver = await context.app.service('users').get(ride.driverId);
      // We can't copy the complete object because field are not filtered by the internal service.
      // @see https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1715
      ride.driver = {
        _id: driver._id,
        name: driver.name,
      };
    }
}
```